# Kerberos is not set up . You cannot login - Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, kerberos, keycloak-services, kerberos-delegation

I had configured the keycloak under the user federation settings as kerberos.

I had also entered the realm ,service principal and the keytab file directory as stated .

But I get the issue as : Kerberos is not set up . You cannot login

In firefox I has enabled SPNEGO as per the below docs :

http://www.microhowto.info/howto/configure_firefox_to_authenticate_using_spnego_and_kerberos.html

I am attaching from the log snippet :

```
2021-06-30 11:43:31,234 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationSelectionResolver] (default task-1) Selections when trying execution 'auth-spnego' : [ authSelection - auth-spnego]
2021-06-30 11:43:31,234 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-1) invoke authenticator.authenticate: auth-spnego
2021-06-30 11:43:31,235 TRACE [org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.SpnegoAuthenticator] (default task-1) Sending back WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
```

Reference to the same issue :

https://marc.info/?l=keycloak-user&m=154803677131797&w=2

Do consider to help us with the concrete solution .

Thanks in advance !